# DataSet darle formato de fecha a una columna del DataTable

Tags: c#, windows-forms, dataset

Trabajo con C# y SQL Server, tengo un dataset que se pobla de información por medio de un sp la columna fecha requiere el formato fecha hora AM/PM el código que ocupo es el siguiente

```
DataSet ds = d.ObtenerCSV(entity);
        ds.Tables[0].Columns["FECHA"]
```

A esa columna del table tengo la necesidad de dale el formato de fecha hora AM/PM, he intentado lo siguiente:

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns["FECHA"].ToString("tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Me da error en tostring me parece que no acepta parametros.

El tipo de dato es cadena en el `datatable` la columna que contiene esa información es de tipo `string`.

Deseo obtener este formato 5/15/2021 8:32 AM

Estoy usando un método de extensión

```
public static class MetodoExtension
{
    public static void Convert<T>(this DataColumn column, Func<object, T> conversion)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in column.Table.Rows)
        {
             row[column] = conversion(row[column]);
        }
    }
}
```

Lo aplico así

```
DataSet ds = d.ObtenerCSV(entity);
        ds.Tables[0].Columns["FECHA"].Convert(
            val => DateTime.Parse(val.ToString()).ToString("tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

> Me da el siguiente error: La cadena no se reconoció como una fecha y
> hora válida. No se pudo almacenar  en la columna FECHA. El tipo
> esperado es DateTime.

Estoy usando una fecha valida `2021-05-15 08:32:00.000` es una fecha en uso `8601`

Saludos!

Comment: El código que utilizas debería funcionar, pero solo producirá `AM` o `PM` sin la hora. Esto asumiendo que la columna `FECHA` sea del tipo correcto y no sea `null`. Puedes especificar cual es el tipo de dato y un ejemplo del resultado que quieres obtener por favor. [Documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#lowercase-hour-h-format-specifier)

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez ya actualice

Comment: Para prodicir el resultado que buscas debes usar `.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` pero el error no es por el formato porque tal como está funciona como te mencioné en mi comentario anterior. De acuerdo con el mensaje de error que mencionas, el problema parece estar en los datos y no veo  una validación antes del `DateTime.Parse` ni tienes un `try..catch` para atrapar la exception. Considera validar los datos antes de intentar convertirlos.

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez la fecha que obtengo poniendo lo que me indicas son números y puntos

Comment: En el ejemplo que probé con base en la información que aportaste en la pregunta, esta instrucción `DateTime.Parse("2021-05-15 08:32:00.000".ToString()).ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` produce este resultado `5/15/2021 08:32 AM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto no responde exactamente pero te indico una alternativa que he usado cuando el sp/vista/tabla, etc te devuelve un formato pero quieres mostrar otro y no puedes editar el sp/vista/tabla, etc.

Puedes copiar el dataset a otro pero le indicas el DataType de tu columna fecha sea string

```
DataTable dtCloned = dt_documentos.Clone();
dtCloned.Columns["ColFecha"].DataType = typeof(String);
foreach (DataRow row in dt_documentos.Rows)
{
   dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Luego, modificas esa columna con el formato de fecha que necesites.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtCloned.Rows)
{
   string fechaDoc = row[1].ToString();
   fechaDoc = DateTime.Parse(fechaDoc).ToString(@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
   row["ColFecha"] = fechaDoc;
}
```

Con eso, puedes usar el DataSet "dtCloned" en vez del que originalmente tuviste.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos espero mi aporte te ayude.

Lo que yo hago en estos casos en los cuales quiero mostrar un formato de fecha específico es hacer un procedimiento almacenado que me regrese la fecha formateada como la quiero.

Código de formateo:

```
DATE_FORMAT(FechaCita, '%d/%b/%Y %H:%i') as FechaCita
```

Este código es de MySQL y la hora esta en formato de 24 horas pero puedes buscar su similar en Sql y ejemplo de salida: 27/06/2022 16:04

Comment: El formateado de fechas, números, etc. debería hacerse en la parte de vista del código y no en el acceso a la base de datos / modelo para una mejor planificación y que la aplicación sea más susceptible (si no se hace desde el principio) de utilizarse para internacionalización